# Is "Hi alls" used in English?

Tags: slang, colloquialisms, neologisms, non-standard

Some my friends usually use "Hi alls!" for greeting a group of people.

I don't think it's right, we cannot use "all" with "s" suffix.

We are from Vietnam and are not native English speakers. Is this right in native English standard?

- Is "Hi alls" wrong?

Comment: Please state the nationality of your friends, thanks. This could be a regional thing.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: We are from Vietnam and are not native English speaker. Is this right in native English standard?

Comment: The expression *Y'all* with variations is the archetypal address for *You all* of the American South. Even *Shalom, Y'all*. In Brooklyn, we said *Youz*. English otherwise has no way to differentiate the singular you from the plural.

Comment: Short answer, no. But maybe in some dialects across the US, it might be heard and used. My first thought was also directed to **Y'all** and its spelling variants and use. In fact, there is a question on EL&U asking about its plural form [When is “all y'allses” used?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145717/when-is-all-yallses-used)

Comment: The pronoun "all" incorporates a plural meaning. Just saying "Hi all" or "Hello all" or [*Good morning all!*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323033/proper-way-to-address-a-very-small-group-that-includes-both-sexes/323043#323043) is sufficient, there is no need to add the suffix "s". In emails it's common to address the recipients as "all" as in [***Dear all***](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292/is-it-appropriate-to-use-the-salutation-dear-all-in-a-work-email). The "s' in "alls" is redundant.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Yes, I think it is redundant too. Thanks for answering.

Comment: As a casual, personalized greeting there's absolutely nothing wrong with it.  Many people have idiosyncratic greetings they use in casual situations.

Comment: Slang/informal: 45,200 results on Google for "Hi alls!" (Not all may be valid or relevant).

Answer (score -1):

Agreed, 'Hi alls' doesn't sound great to my ears. But, you can have an 's' after the word all, albiet with an apostrophe('). For example,

> 'All's well that ends well'

Here, the 's' doesn't try to make it plural, but is a contraction of "all" and "is". So it literally translates to

> 'All is well that ends well'

Comment: All's in *your* example is a *contraction* of "all" and "is". Not plural. The "alls" in the OP's example "Hi, alls" is plural in meaning.

Comment: @Mari-LouA So does that mean "Hi Alls" is correct? or even alls for that matter.

Comment: Please read the comments underneath the author's post. Everything you need to know is "all" there. :)

Comment: Ah sorry should've done that earlier. Thank you @Mari-LouA